# Not Get accurate Location using Google Location API in Android

Tags: android, google-location-services

We have built an Android App which is currently used in Saudi Arabia, where we are fetching User's Location while the user clicks on specific button.

We are fetching location until 5 seconds using Google Location API and as per our requirement, we need to get accuracy less than 50.

In some of the cases we are getting this accuracy, but for some of the cases we are getting that accuracy more than 100 to 2000.

We have built this functionality using below code.

```
public class LocationService implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {
     private LocationRequest locationRequest;
     private GoogleApiClient locationClient;
     private Context tempContext = null;
     public static Location mLastLocation = null;
     public Handler mHandler = null;
    long Id = 0;

 public LocationService(Context context) {
  try {
    tempContext = context;

   if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(tempContext) == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
        locationRequest.setInterval(ConstantData.ACTION_LOCATIONTIME_INTERVAL); // 2000
        locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

        locationClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(tempContext)
              .addApi(LocationServices.API)
              .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
              .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).build();

        if (!locationClient.isConnected() || !locationClient.isConnecting()) {
            locationClient.connect();
        }

        LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
            .addLocationRequest(locationRequest);
        builder.setNeedBle(true);

   }
  } 
  catch (Exception e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
  }

 }

 @Override
 public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
 }

 @Override
 public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  try {
    mLastLocation = getLocation();
    PendingResult<Status> pendingResult = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi
     .requestLocationUpdates(locationClient, locationRequest, this);

    getLocation task = new getLocation();
    task.execute((Void) null);

  } 
  catch (Exception e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
 }

 public Location getLocation() {
    return LocationServices.FusedLocationApi
        .getLastLocation(locationClient);
 }

 public void stopLocationUpdates() {
  try {
   if (locationClient != null && locationClient.isConnected()) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(locationClient, this);
        locationClient.disconnect();
        locationClient = null;
   }
  } 
  catch (Exception e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
 }

 private class getLocation extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
 @Override
  protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
   int limit = 0, totaltry = 0;
   try 
   {
    totaltry = 10;
    while (limit < totaltry) {
     Thread.sleep(500);
     mLastLocation = getLocation();
     if (mLastLocation != null
       && mLastLocation.getAccuracy() < 50)
      break;
     limit++;
    }

   } 
   catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
   }

   return null;
  }

  protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
   try 
   {
       stopLocationUpdates();
   } 
   catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
  }
 }
```

Currently, we are trying to implement the same functionality with using below link as a reference.

http://adavis.info/2014/09/android-location-updates-with-the-fusedlocationapi.html